# How to use navigationBar in Navigator?

Tags: react-native

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html#content

> **navigationBar** node
>
> Optionally provide a navigation bar that persists across scene
>   transitions

The documentation gives no examples or idea what this parameter expects. I'm using `Navigator` and noticed there's no top bar with route title and back button, so I assume I have to add it somehow using `navigationBar`, but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use it like this:

```
<Navigator 
  initialRoute={{name: 'My First Scene', index: 0}}
  renderScene={(route, navigator) => {
    return <Page navigator={navigator}  name={route.name} index={route.index}/>  }}
  navigationBar={
    <Navigator.NavigationBar routeMapper={NavigationBarRouteMapper}  />}
/>

var NavigationBarRouteMapper = {
  LeftButton(route, navigator, index, navState) {
    if(index > 0) {
      return (
      <TouchableHighlight  style={{marginTop: 10}} onPress={() => {
            if (index > 0) {
              navigator.pop();
            } 
        }}>
       <Text>Back</Text>
     </TouchableHighlight>
 )} else {
 return null}
 },
  RightButton(route, navigator, index, navState) {
    return null;
  },
  Title(route, navigator, index, navState) {
    return <Text>My Title</Text>
  }
};
```

[Here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Examples/UIExplorer/Navigator/NavigationBarSample.js) is the React Native Navigation Bar sample project folder: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Examples/UIExplorer/Navigator/NavigationBarSample.js

Two other ways to learn more about this:

1. Download [React Native](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/) and run the [Navigator Examples](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/Examples/UIExplorer/Navigator) in the [UI Explorer project](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/Examples/UIExplorer) ( which in of itself is a cool place to learn about all of the native modules / components ).
2. [Here](https://rnplay.org/apps/8EgHhQ) is a RNPlay project with the navigationBar implemented.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful! But in your navigation mapper, how did you know to use properties `LeftButton`, `RightButton`, and `Title`, and what arguments those took?

Comment: Sure, check out https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/CustomComponents/Navigator/NavigatorNavigationBar.js . Look at the proptypes. Also https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/Libraries/CustomComponents/Navigator for more info on the Navigator under the hood.